# JavaScript audio file not playing on flask server

Tags: javascript, flask, audio

The error i am getting is :

Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found.

path of audio file is correct !

My code :
[image of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3OCaN.png)

Comment: Can you please provide full code sample, better JS fiddle? Image with code is not the best option how to help us debug your code.

Answer (score 0):

as mdn says, the constructor expects url (DOMString) to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement/Audio

so, maybe it will be better to pass the url like localhost:3000/src/audio/your_file.mp3 to show browser what to load from server, also check if this file is accessible